# regex, test phone numbers ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

Any phone numbers that begin with these ranges correct: ex: **772123322**

The length is important, it should contain 6 digits at the end

```
550-559
700-709
770-779
```

so, i've done this so far:

```
\A(55[0-9])|(70[0-9])|(77[0-9])\d{6}\z
```

How can modify this regex to work properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\A(55[0-9]|70[0-9]|77[0-9])\d{6}\z
```

Answer (score 5):

Simpler is:

```
/^(55|70|77)\d{7}$/
```

Comment: This is good, however you need to be aware of the security implications with `^$` in ruby regexps. See section 7.6: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#regular-expressions .Use `\A\z` instead.

Comment: @Casper it's an interesting point but in this case we are matching lines, not validating activerecord models so ^$ is more correct. In other words text.scan(myregex) will behave correctly while text.scan(yourregex) will not.